Looking for blazing fast Solana RPC
I'm looking for a Solana RPC provider which offers extremely low latency, with maximum up to 2-3 seconds, ideally between 1-2 seconds or less. I am building a trading bot so performance and reliability are crucial.
I have so far tried Helius, Quicknode and Alchemy. The free plans are not good enough, they take 20-30 seconds and often rate limit. I also upgraded to a helius paid plan but it was not any better in terms of performance, only offered higher rate limits.
Does anyone have an experienced with a provider that offers such performance and reliability?
Thanks

Give Chainstack a shot: https://chainstack.com/build-better-with-solana/
Disclaimer: I'm the founder of Chainstack

From a personal experience maybe check out triton one. It's not the cheapest provider out there but is often cited as subjectively faster than most.
Also, a lot of factors such as your ISP latency could be affecting this and maybe you should look into that as well.
You should also look into this list and see which one works best for you https://solana.com/rpc
Most of the free services here as you've noted are severely rate-limited, you might need to purchase a plan to try out
